# Can i format the Note section of Email to have HTML in Docusign Templates?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to understand if I can add HTML elements to the note in DOCUSIGN template.

The reason is I want certain text of NOTE to be BOLD and certain to be regular characters.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing, it's possible to specify **BOLD** text within a note by using the API, but not by using the DocuSign web console (UI).

For example, if I submit a "Create Envelope" API request with the following **recipients** structure -- including a recipient note that specifies **BOLD text** -- the bold text correctly renders both in the email that the recipient receives, as well as in the Note that's displayed to the recipient when they open the Envelope:

```
<recipients>
  <signers>
    <signer>
     <email>johnsemail@outlook.com</email>
     <name>John Doe</name>
     <recipientId>1</recipientId>
     <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>  
     <note>Test note with &lt;b&gt;BOLD text&lt;/b&gt;.</note>
     <tabs>
        <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
                <documentId>1</documentId>
                <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                <xPosition>10</xPosition>
                <yPosition>100</yPosition>
            </signHere>
        </signHereTabs>
    </tabs>
    </signer>
  </signers>
</recipients>
```

[image: DS note]

However, using that same technique to specify bold text within a Note using the DocuSign web console (UI) doesn't work -- the text is NOT bold in either the email that the recipient receives or in the note they see within the Envelope itself.  i.e., here's how I specified the Note via the DocuSign UI:

[image: DS console note]

And here's how it renders both in the email and in the Envelope for the recipient:

[image: Note in Envelope]

Comment: I had the same effect i thought escaping the characters would help me. But still not sure as they are APEX based programming thought there might be a work around to achieve formatting through UI.